# adding fields to database without changing views mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, razor

I am currently working on a MVC4 website to administer some customers and vehicles, if the database changes such as adding a field, is there a way of generating the view as not to hard code the fields and controls.

for instance a view as such

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>customer</legend>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
    </div>

 <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

now lets say I want to add another field to the database, say address I have to add the change to the view. Can this be done in a dynamic way.

Comment: You could do it using reflection, or storing the database field names in your model and iterating over them, but there's a point where what is easy to write becomes difficult to read/understand and I think you might cross it trying to get your solution to cover all eventualities.

Comment: Are you trying to edit those fields in the View, or just print them out as a Label?

Comment: using CRUD so it will need to be edit where needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are prepared to change your model class then you can use [Html.DisplayForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayformodel%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) (for read-only views) or [Html.EditorForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) (for editable views), which will auto-generate HTML on the basis of the properties of your model.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using a T4 template to generate your models from columns in a database table:  http://highoncoding.com/Articles/557_Code_Generation_Using_T4_Templates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [MvcScaffolding](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding/) NuGet package is made precisely for that. You can read more about it here: 
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/